# @(_:_), how does it work in pattern matching

Tags: haskell

This is an example taken from o' reilly - [real world haskell](https://github.com/cyga/real-world-haskell/blob/master/ch15/MovieReview.hs#L34).

```
maybeReview alist = do
  title <- lookup1 "title" alist
  return (MovieReview title)'

lookup1 key alist = case lookup key alist of
                      Just (Just s@(_:_)) -> Just s
                      _ -> Nothing
```

How does the `@` symbol work here in the line,

```
Just (Just s@(_:_)) -> Just s
```

How does it match a non-empty value?

Comment: I'd have used a guard: `Just (Just s) | not (null s) -> Just s`.

Comment: Although yours is not the case, it is good to know such pattern can [force strictness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627849/turn-off-lazy-evaluation-in-haskell) (see Daniel Wagner's comment under the first answer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`_` is a wildcard. It says make sure there is a value here but I don't want to bind it to any variable. `:` is the constructor for a list. On the left is one value and the right is the rest of the list. The rest of the list can be empty. So if you do something like this:

```
(x:xs)
```

x is the first element of the list and xs can be an empty list or it can be an infinite amount of elements.

```
(x:y:xs)
```

Would only match lists with at least 2 elements. The `@` is the at pattern. It binds the entirety of the right expression to the left variable.

```
m@(Just _)
```

Here `m` would have the type `Maybe a`. The `_` is just used because `Just` is of type `a -> Maybe a` and we need to have a placeholder for its argument. So `m` binds to the whole value of (Just _). In your example.

```
s@(_:_)
```

`s` is the whole list. And `(_:_)` specifies that the list must have at least one element or the match will fail. If we wrote:

```
s@(x:xs)
```

`x` would be the first element and `xs` would be the tail of the list. `s == x:xs` would return `True`. But since we don't need the head or the tail we simply use `_`.

Answer (score 5):

An explanation by examples...

Let "the pattern" refer to `Just (Just s@(_:_))`. Below is a list of various values and whether or not those values match the pattern. If there is a match then `s` will be set to a part of the value and can be used on the RHS of the pattern guard.

1. value = `Nothing` - does not match
2. value = `Just Nothing` - does not match
3. value = `Just (Just [])` - does not match
4. value = `Just (Just [3,4,5])` - matches and `s = [3,4,5]`
5. value = `Just (Just [6])` - does match and `s = [6]`
6. value = `Just (Just [1,2])` - matches and `s = [1,2]`

Comment: `Just (Just [6])` does match since `[6] = 6 : []`.